# How much of an effect do large arrays have on efficiency?

Tags: android

I am thinking of storing large arrays in my app. The biggest they would be is 100000 elements. But could settle for 1000. 
I have an option of exporting them to csv files. Having them in the app would be neater.
How much does having arrays of this size affect the phone's efficiency and performance?
Suggestions and thoughts appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you want to use sqlite database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store just 100'000 numbers (as .csv files imply), this won't have any effect on your performance, since in case of int it will be just 400kb which is quite a small amount of memory for modern android phones.

P.S. I recommend you first implementing your app in any way, and then, when you will see what the problems are, be it memory consumption, battery drain or whatever, optimize it.

Comment: Well it's a data logger and it's working, so I'm wondering should I regularly export the data to plot it or can I regularly plot it on the phone and export to .csv at long intervals. How many MB before it does start effecting performance?

Comment: @Rokky100 I think you should experiment with it. It also depends on the amout of memory on a phone you use.